# jquery return null value for background in firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have following html

```
<div style="opacity: 1; min-height: 405px; background: url(/website_blog/static/src/img/library/gauze-green-texture.jpg) repeat scroll 0px 0px / cover  rgb(8, 8, 8);" class="js_fullheight"></div>
```

now in my jquery i m trying to get 'background' then it work fine for chrome but in firefox it return "" string

```
    var cover_background = $('.js_fullheight').css('background');
```

the it rerun null. so please give me solution for that. i dont want 'background-image'.

My clear question is that i only want using only 'background' not using background-image or background-color. And as i mention this work in chrome but not in firefox , so i want reason why this is not supported in firefox ?? its my problem or generic problem ???

Comment: try to use background-image

Comment: use separate `background` properties  with JS/jQuery e.g. `backgroundImage` `backgroundColor`, `backgroundPosition` Example `$('.js_fullheight').css('backgroundImage')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this ...

```
var backgroundProperty = $(".js_fullheight").get(0).style.background;
```

Result:

```
 "url("/website_blog/static/src/img/library/gauze-green-texture.jpg")
 repeat scroll 0px 0px / cover  rgb(8, 8, 8)"
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mz_arain08/0ca7o8gL/)

Please see this following refference 
[REF](http://www.sitepoint.com/change-css-jquery/)

Comment: duplicate answer. look at @Dhaval Bharadva answer. Also OP don't want background image.

Comment: Thanks Zeeshan.... As per my question your ans is perfect.. and that exactly i want...

Answer (score 2):

Your background tag is "inline" or "shorthand" or "all in one". However, it is not valid. You can see [the correct usage on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background#Syntax):

```
background: <image> <position> <size> <repeat> <attachment> <box>{1,2}
/* note: simplified version to fit without scrollbars */
```

For maximum compatibility, you want to keep it simple, and add more advanced features separately:

```
background: <color> <image> <position> <repeat>;
background-size: <size>;
(etc)
```

If your CSS property is not formatted correctly for the browser, it will be ignored. That means it won't even fall back to just the color, and you won't get **any** results from accessing the "background" property via javascript.

You do not want to rely on the `.css("background")` returning in the same order that you specified in your CSS, so you should really retrieve each property yourself:

```
var bg_color = $(element).css('background-color');
var bg_image = $(element).css('background-image');
// etc.
```

Comment: I am confused with the question now, I think the order is the issue, will delete my answer..